# Finding out which type of booking a customer has the biggest average of people booked for

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table called 'BookingsAverage':

```
email       | average_amount  | type
============+=================+==================
A@gmail.com |  8              | gym
A@gmail.com |  7              | pool
B@gmail.com |  2              | gym
B@gmail.com |  10             | pool
B@gmail.com |  25             | other
C@gmail.com |  3              | other
```

I am trying to make a query that returns if either gym or pool have the most average_amount for every email. So this data would result in:

```
email       |  biggest
============+=================
A@gmail.com |  gym
B@gmail.com |  pool
C@gmail.com |  both
```

If an email doesn't have a row for both types and thus only has a row with type 'other' than the average_amount of type 'gym' and 'pool' are assumed to be 0 and equal. This results in the column 'biggest' having the value "both".

If an email has a row with type 'pool' or 'gym' but not with the other, than the biggest will be the type that's present.

How could I accomplish this?

I looked at how to find the row with the biggest value for an email, but this returns the 'other' row when it has the highest average_amount (even though there is a row for an email containing the type 'gym' or 'pool') and also returns two rows if two types have the same average_amount for an email, instead of returning 1 row containing the string 'both'

```
SELECT a.email, a.average_amount, a.type
FROM BookingsAverage a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT email, MAX(average_amount) average_amount
    FROM BookingsAverage
    GROUP BY email
) b ON a.email = b.email AND a.average_amount = b.average_amount
```